# android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat is deprecated

Tags: android

Why does android studio show  `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat` is deprecated  even when I have selected API 15 (IceCream Sandwich) while creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

That API 15 is actually `minSdkVersion` which you select while creating a project which is different from `compileSdkVersion`,Deprecation is based on the version you compile against,if it is higher or equal than the deprecation was added for any particular feature then compiler will give you that warning.

**Note:** Whenever you see the deprecation try finding out better way for that,because that is what it suggests.